# synchronize 1 producer and more than 1 consumer(multithread)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I want to implement the producer-consumer scenario, where there is one producer thread and more than one consumer threads.
let me specific actually, Producer thread needs to create a set of objects at regular interval ( for example, 5 seconds )  and consumer thread's need to be consume the objects.

I am unsure how to create set of objects at regular interval and how syn the multiple consumers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is it that you have problems with? Traditionally, the work queue is protected by a condition lock; if multiple "consumers" are waiting on the same lock, then only one of them will succeed in actually getting it. Instead of grabbing the entire queue, however, you should just grab one object from it, remove it from the queue, and release the lock before processing the job.

As for creating jobs at regular intervals, that's a job for a timer class in whatever library you are using. If you are waiting for input, select() and poll() calls have a timeout value; if you aren't doing anything you could just call [u]sleep().

Comment: +1 for answer that doesn't give the solution, as this is most definitely homework

Answer (score 1):

I won't spell out all the code, but you can use a mutex and a condition variable for this (and a linked list). The basic pattern is that the producer does:

```
loop_forever
    wait_until_interval_has_elapsed
    lock_the_mutex
        append_an_item_to_the_list
        signal_the_condvar // can be outside the mutex
    unlock_the_mutex
```

Each consumer does:

```
loop_forever
    lock_the_mutex
        while(list_is_empty)
            wait_the_condvar
        remove_an_item_from_the_list
    unlock_the_mutex
    process_the_item
```

You can also do it with a mutex and a semaphore:

```
loop_forever
    wait_until_interval_has_elapsed
    lock_the_mutex
        append_an_item_to_the_list
    unlock_the_mutex
    post_the_semaphore

loop_forever
    wait_the_semaphore
    lock_the_mutex
        remove_an_item_from_the_list
    unlock_the_mutex
    process_the_item
```

This is slightly simpler as it stands, but once you decide to add a mechanism to tell the consumers to finish what they're doing and quit you're probably better off with the condition variable because you can "broadcast" it. Semaphores have a slight reputation for being easy to mis-use, which is why C++11 doesn't have a semaphore. Posix does, though, so on linux you have the choice. And to be fair, so does approximately every other multi-threading OS.

A mutex/condvar pair may also give better behavior than a semaphore in the case where your threads have varying priorities. Unlike a mutex, a semaphore doesn't have an "owner", and therefore techniques like priority inheritance are out of the question.

For `wait_until_interval_has_elapsed` use either timers or sleep functions -- be aware that unless you're on a realtime system, you can never be sure that you will be able to run at a particular time, only that you will be woken on or after a particular time.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a counting-semaphore to signal the count of available widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to need a way to tell the consumer threads that there are new objects available. Here's an example (I didn't include the `#include`s):

```
#define NUM_CONSUMERS 2

static int objects[4]; //The place for produced objects
static pthread_mutex_t cond_mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void* producer_func(void* arg);
void* consumer_func(void* arg);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  pthread_t producer;
  pthread_t consumers[NUM_CONSUMERS];
  int res;
  void* zero = 0;
  res = pthread_create(&producer, NULL, producer_func, zero); 
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CONSUMERS; i++) {
    res = pthread_create(&consumers[i], NULL, consumer_func, zero);
  }
}

void* producer(void* arg) {
  while(1) {
    objects[0] = 0;
    objects[1] = 1;
    objects[2] = 2;
    objects[3] = 3;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cond_mut);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cond_mut);
    sleep(5);
  }
}

void* consumer(void* arg) {
  while(1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cond_mut);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cond_mut);
    //Process objects here 
  }
}
```